# Inline-if always uses the true condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, if-statement, web

I was writing some reactJS code, when I wanted some conditional rendering. For that I made an inline-if, that renders a component if the variable `rememberMe` is true, but the code always renders the "if it's true part". Help would be appreciated.

```
    const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'))
    const [asWho, setAsWho] = useState(localStorage.getItem('asWho'))

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', false)
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'))
        console.log(rememberMe)
        if (rememberMe === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', false)
            setRememberMe(false)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            { rememberMe ? <GroupList test={rememberMe} /> : <PleaseLogIn /> }
        </div>
    )
```

I printed `rememberMe` in `<GroupList />` and it even prints false. Help would be much apprechiated.

```
export default function GroupList(params) {
    console.log(params.test)
    return (
        <div>
            logged in
            <br/>
            remember: {params.test}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What will happen if you -for a test- call `setRememberMe(false)` outside from `if (rememberMe === null)`?

Comment: Then it works, the `rememberMe` is false and so the other Code gets called. That behavious is weird tho, because when I print rememberMe right above the `if (rememberMe === null )` it already is false

Comment: According your answer for my question and the answers below, the result of your if query was never true and the sate of `rememberMe` has been never changed to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first let's look at what `localStorage.getItem('rememberMe')` returns:

```
console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'))
// Result
>> "string"
```

Any string value placed in `if` or ternary `if-else` will be evaluate as `true`.

Let's look at this:

```
// These lines will always print true whether string is "false" or  "true"
console.log(Boolean(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe')))
console.log(Boolean("false"))
console.log(Boolean("true"))
// Result
>> true
>> true
>> true
```

When you are using if statement any expression is converted to `Boolean` so any `string` (if it is not empty) will evaluate as `true`

So, You need to compare if it's `"false"` ( Or `"true"`)

```
const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') == 'true')
const [asWho, setAsWho] = useState(localStorage.getItem('asWho') == 'true')

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', false)
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'))
    console.log(rememberMe)
    if (rememberMe === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', false)
        setRememberMe(false)
    }
}, [])

return (
  <div>
      {rememberMe ? <GroupList test={rememberMe} /> : <PleaseLogIn />}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Oh wow! That was actually it. Kind of weird that it does not save it as a boolean, but rather as a String. Thanks for your help tho, I was on this problem for a long time.

Comment: Not exactly true. `if ("") console.log("An empty string is not truthy")` Except for `true` and `false` in JavaScript one also has truthy and falsy. Some strings will be truthy, but others will be falsy (such as an empty string). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: I have mentioned that if string is empty it will be evaluated as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStorage` save strings values, the first time your component render it will get the item 'rememberMe` from the localstorage

```js
const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'));
```

and it will be `null` because such a key doesn't exist yet in the localstorage, then the `useEffect` part works after the component render

```js
    useEffect(() => {
       
        localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', false);
        ....
    }, [])
```

Localstorage will convert the `false` to a string like `String(false)` because it only save as string.

so it becamse in localstorage as { "rememberMe": "false" }

the next time you refresh your page you have

```js
const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(localStorage.getItem('rememberMe'));
```

the

```
localStorage.getItem('rememberMe')
```

will resolve to `"false"` as a `string` (remember that)

when your component render we have the ternary operater that check for the value if it's truthy or not

```js
{ rememberMe ? <GroupList test={rememberMe} /> : <PleaseLogIn /> }
```

is equal to

```js
{ Boolean(rememberMe) ? <GroupList test={rememberMe} /> : <PleaseLogIn /> }
```

which means checking for `Boolean('false')` which will be resolved to `true` and will always display `<GroupList test={rememberMe} />`.

what we want to focus on:

- localstorage always save and get `string` values
- in js `Boolean(some_string_value)` will be resolved to `true`